# how to compute weakest condition?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, semantics

```
if(x < y) 
     x = x + 1
    else
     x = 3 * x 
    {x < 0}
```

my answer :

```
 x+1<0 --> x<-1

 x*3<0 --> x<0
```

so weakest condition is (x<-1) ∩ (x<0) = x<-1
However, the answer sheet says that x<0 is the answer. How can I get the weakest condition?

Comment: Doesn't `y` need to be part of the condition? Do you have additional knowledge about `y`?

Comment: no. Only information was given to find the weakest precondition in the conditional statement below.